# Finding a linear mapping given span of the kernel

Tags: linear-algebra

Finding a linear mapping  given the span of the kernel,  where u=(1,2,3,4) and v=(0,1,1,1)  now if u and v span kernel then how can I find the linear mapping?

Comment: There are infinitely many linear transformations with that kernel. Do you mean just find any such linear transformation?

Comment: Sorry it will be linear mapping .  Not transformation .

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. The two terms are usually interchangeable.

Comment: I need complete solution in elementary way  can  you please give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete $u,v$ to a basis say $\{u,v,(0,0,1,1),(0,0,0,1)\}$ and define

$f: u\to 0, \ v\to0,\ (0,0,1,1)\to (0,0,1,1),\ (0,0,0,1)\to (0,0,0,1)$

Then $f$ is linear with the appropriate kernel

*Every linear map is determined by its image of some basis. For your example you want a linear map $f:\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}^4$ so if a have a basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}$ then $f(x,y,z,w)=xf(e_1)+yf(e_2)+zf(e_3)+wf(e_4)$. So I just complete the set of $\{u,v\}$ into a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ ny adding two vectors s.t. the whole set is linearly idependent. Now I have to find a map $f$ with kernel $\{u,v\}$ so it has to be $f(u)=f(v)=0$. For the other two vectors of the basis I have to choose their images to be linearly independent.*

It is $e_1=u-2v-(0,0,1,1)-(0,0,0,1)$

$e_2=v-(0,0,1,1)$

$e_3=(0,0,1,1)-(0,0,0,1)$

$e_4=(0,0,0,1)$

So $$f(x,y,z,w)=xf(e_1)+yf(e_2)+zf(e_3)+wf(e_4)= \\ x[f(u)-2f(v)-f(0,0,1,1)-f(0,0,0,1)]+y[f(v)-f(0,0,1,1)]+ z[f(0,0,1,1)-f(0,0,0,1)]+wf(0,0,0,1)= \\ x(0,0,-1,-2)+y(0,0,-1,-1)+z(0,0,1,0)+w(0,0,0,1)=(0,0,-x-y+z,-2x-y+w)$$

Comment: Actually I did not understand your answer.  Can you please give me another solution in a elementary way ?  I am new to Linear algebra

Comment: @Shaafi Ahmed Qazi I added some details

Comment: But in my book  the solution is   f(x,y,z,t) = (x+y-z,  2x+y-t, 0)

Comment: For the other two vectors of the basis you have to choose something _nonzero_, else you would get a different, bigger kernel.

Comment: @Chris Custer  Yes you right

Comment: @Shaafi Ahmed Qazi  That is one solution. There are more than one maps that satisfy your conditions

Comment: Oh I just can not understand your answer,  I think you are giving in an advanced way,  But I am not advance in Linear algebra ,  please try to answer it in basic way so I can understand

Comment: What do you know about linear maps?

Comment: I know a little bit and I am learning Linear algebra ,

Comment: @ChrisCuster Not only should they be sent to something nonzero, but they should also be sent to linearly independent vectors. Otherwise the kernel couldn't be spanned by $u$ and $v$.

Comment: @twosigma Forgive me about that. I'm just writing without thinking

Comment: @twosigma nice catch. forgot about that.

Comment: Please give me the solution

Comment: @Shaafi Ahmed Qazi I further edited my answer

Comment: How do you choose the two vectors (0,0,1,1)  and  (0,0,0,1) ?

Comment: @Shaafi Ahmed Qazi I completed the set $\{u,v\}$ to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Extend $\{u, v\}$ to a basis $\{ u, v, x, y \}$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Step 2: Define the linear mapping $f: \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ by the following: $f(u) = 0, f(v) = 0$; as for $f(x)$ and $f(y)$, they can be any two linearly independent vectors.

---

***In more detail***

Here is a systematic way to do Steps 1 and 2 (that also works in general).

**Step 1**: To extend a set to a basis, you can do the following process that also works more generally: put the vectors into the rows of a matrix. In this case, we have $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. Then reduce this matrix. Find which variables are free variables, then add on the standard basis vectors corresponding to those free variables. For example, in this case, the matrix reduces to $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 1 & 2\\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. The free variables correspond to the $3$rd and $4$th columns, so we add on the standard basis vectors $e_3 = (0, 0, 1, 0)$ and $e_4 = (0, 0, 0, 1)$. Then our new set $\{u, v, e_3, e_4\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$.

**Why does this work?** Well, since elementary row operations don’t change the row space, we can reduce the matrix without changing the space spanned by the vectors that we put as the rows of the matrix. Reducing the matrix makes it easier to see which variables are free variables, so that we can add on the standard basis vectors corresponding to those free variables, which will extend our original set of vectors to a basis of the whole space.

**Step 2**: Step 2 works basically because we have the following theorem from linear algebra (which you can try to prove as an exercise if you want):

- **Theorem**: Suppose $V, W$ are vector spaces. Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional, say $v_1, …, v_n$ is a basis for $V$. Let $w_1, …, w_n$ be any $n$ vectors (not necessarily distinct) in $W$. Then there exists a unique linear mapping $T: V \to W$ such that $Tv_i = w_i$ for each $i \in \{1, …, n \}$.

So, for your case, we have $V = \mathbb{R}^4$, $v_1 = u = (1, 2, 3, 4), v_2 = v = (0, 1, 1, 1)$, and we want $w_1 = (0, 0, 0, 0), w_2 = (0, 0, 0, 0)$. We need to find $v_3$ and $v_4$ to extend the set $\{u, v\}$ to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$, which has been done in Step 1. And for $w_3, w_4$, you can choose any two linearly independent vectors. Then (Exercise) $\{u, v\}$ is a basis for the kernel and, as the Theorem guarantees, the mapping defined by $Tv_i = w_i$ for all $i \in \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ is indeed linear. We have specified the linear mapping completely because we have specified what it does to the vectors of a basis.